# I am installing polymer in visual studio code but there are many errors I am getting a lot of errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, polymer

C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install -g bower

npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.8: We don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read how to migrate legacy project here: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
C:\Users\Deepanshi\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Users\Deepanshi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower

- bower@1.8.8
  added 1 package from 1 contributor in 14.243s

C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install -g polymer-cli@next
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Deepanshi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\bin\polymer.js
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\Deepanshi\AppData\Roaming\npm\polymer
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\Deepanshi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\bin\polymer.js' -> 'C:\Users\Deepanshi\AppData\Roaming\npm\polymer'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Deepanshi\AppData\Roaming\npm\polymer
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Deepanshi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-10-07T12_56_44_680Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
npm i -g --force npm (note the --force flag)

If your output is get running npm install -g npm:
You can fix it with "brew reinstall node"

So :

brew reinstall node

npm i -g --force npm